# Force JMS Serialiser to output an object keyed by a specific field

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, jms-serializer

I have an entity *Product* with a one-to-many relationship to an entity *Property*. When I serialise a product instance using the JMS Serialiser I get the following JSON output:

```
{
    "id": 123,
    "name": "Mankini Thong",
    "properties": [{
        "label": "Minimal size",
        "name": "min_size",
        "value": "S"
    }, {
        "label": "Maximum size",
        "name": "max_size",
        "value": "XXXL"
    }, {
        "label": "colour",
        "name": "Colour",
        "value": "Office Green"
    }]
}
```

I try to get the serialiser to serialise the properties collection as an object in which a certain field is used as key. For instance, the *name* field. The desired output is:

```
{
    "id": 123,
    "name": "Mankini Thong",
    "properties": {
        "min_size": {
            "label": "Minimal size",
            "value": "S"
        }, 
        "max_size": {
            "label": "Maximum size",
            "value": "XXXL"
        }, 
        "colour": {
            "label": "Colour",
            "value": "Office Green"
        }
    }
}
```

What would be the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out:

First add a virtual property to the serialisation mapping and exclude the original `properties` field. My configuration is in yaml but using annotations shouldn't be that different:

```
properties:
    properties:
        exclude: true
virtual_properties:
    getKeyedProperties:
        serialized_name: properties
        type: array<Foo\BarBundle\Document\Property>
```

Then I've added the `getKeyedProperties` method to the document class in `Foo\BarBundle\Document\Article`:

```
/**
 * Get properties keyed by name
 *
 * Use the following annotations in case you defined your mapping using
 * annotations instead of a Yaml or Xml file:
 *
 * @Serializer\VirtualProperty
 * @Serializer\SerializedName("properties")
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getKeyedProperties()
{
    $results = [];

    foreach ($this->getProperties() as $property) {
        $results[$property->getName()] = $property;
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Now, the serialised output contains an object properties which are serialised article properties keyed by name.